# How to save two textboxes values into one table coulmn in php

Tags: php

I need to save `firstName` and `lastName` for the `fullName`. I wrote some code. But, This is not working properly. Please, can anyone help me?

```
$student['FULL_NAME'] = $student['FIRST_NAME'] . ' ' . $student['MIDDLE_NAME'];

echo '<tr><td>Full Name</td><td>:</td><td>' . TextInput( $student['FULL_NAME'] , 'students[FULL_NAME]', '', 'size=150 class=cell_medium') . '</td></tr>';
```

Comment: Guessing you need to add `$student['LAST_NAME'];` to the end of the middle name `. ' ' . $student['MIDDLE_NAME']` so `. ' ' . $student['MIDDLE_NAME'] . ' ' . $student['LAST_NAME'];`

Comment: Please show us the expected results

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, It is not saving in the database

Comment: @rbaskam, I need to do `FIRST_NAME` + `MIDDLE_NAME` insert to the database as one column.

Comment: There's nothing in your code, question or tags that mentions a database. The code you've posted is outputting data in a HTML table, not a database table. You need to give us _all_ the relevant code, the expected result and what result you're currently getting. We can only help you with the info you give us.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I need to fix only this concatenate things. `fullName` = `firstName` with `middleName`. Like that. Do I want to create array or something ?

Comment: I don't understand your issue. There's nothing wrong with the concatenation you have as long as the `$student`-array contains the correct values. Again, you need to show us a _complete_ example of the results you _want_ and the results your currently _getting_. Saying "I need to fix" without explaining what doesn't work is useless.